# Why the same code can not be compiled in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix-mta, ubuntu-12.04

I just installed postfix 2.7.11 in Ubuntu server from source code. I do not use the ubuntu own one because I need the old version.

I found a very interesting problem. Before, in both CentOS 5 and 6, I can build the source code without any problem. But, in Ubuntu server 12.04 is totally different.

I got the following problems:

```
dict_nis.c:173: error: undefined reference to 'yp_match'<br>
dict_nis.c:187: error: undefined reference to 'yp_match'<br>

dns_lookup.c:347: error: undefined reference to '__dn_expand'<br>
dns_lookup.c:218: error: undefined reference to '__res_search'<br>
dns_lookup.c:287: error: undefined reference to '__dn_expand'<br>
dns_lookup.c:498: error: undefined reference to '__dn_expand'<br>
dns_lookup.c:383: error: undefined reference to '__dn_expand'<br>
```

Yes, this reason is obviously. I just search related library and add it to the makefile. It works.

The question is why? What is the difference between Ubuntu Server and CentOS?

One possibility is gcc and ld version. Ubuntu server use different version of gcc and ld with CentOS. But I am not sure.

Comment: IIRC postfix is `autoconf` based, so if you can post the `config.log`, or just look into it yourself first, you can see why it fails on detecting the needed library.

Comment: Hi @favoretti I can not find the config.log, could you tell me how to find it? One thing I should mention is when I install postfix from source, I do not need run ./configure before make. In fact, I can run make directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with others help. I found the reason. 
Ubuntu have special .so location. The location is different from CentOS. 
But in Postfix makedefs file, it do not include this specific location. Let's check the source:

```
SYSLIBS="-ldb"
        for name in nsl resolv
        do
            for lib in /usr/lib64 /lib64 /usr/lib /lib
            do
            test -e $lib/lib$name.a -o -e $lib/lib$name.so && {
                SYSLIBS="$SYSLIBS -l$name"
                break
            }
            done
        done
```

Here, SYSLIBS will be used when do make. This script will check some special folder to add .so lib. But these locations do not include Ubuntu's.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 12.04 and postfix 2.9.3 with vda-patch 2.9.1

```
gcc -Wmissing-prototypes -Wformat -DDEBIAN -DMAX_DYNAMIC_MAPS -DHAS_PCRE -DHAS_LDAP -DHAS_SQLITE -DMYORIGIN_FROM_FILE -DNO_NIS -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAS_CDB -DHAS_MYSQL -I/usr/include/mysql -DHAS_PGSQL -I/usr/include/postgresql -DHAS_SQLITE -I/usr/include -DHAS_SSL -I/usr/include/openssl -DUSE_SASL_AUTH -I/usr/include/sasl -DUSE_CYRUS_SASL -DUSE_TLS  -O2 -I. -I../../include -DLINUX3 -o smtpd smtpd.o smtpd_token.o smtpd_check.o smtpd_chat.o smtpd_state.o smtpd_peer.o smtpd_sasl_proto.o smtpd_sasl_glue.o smtpd_proxy.o smtpd_xforward.o smtpd_dsn_fix.o smtpd_milter.o smtpd_resolve.o smtpd_expand.o ../../lib/libmaster.a ../../lib/libtls.a ../../lib/libdns.a ../../lib/libxsasl.a ../../lib/libmilter.a ../../lib/libglobal.a ../../lib/libutil.a -lssl -lcrypto -lsasl2 -lpthread -L/usr/src/postfix-2.9.3/debian -ldb
../../lib/libdns.a: undefined reference to `__res_search'
../../lib/libdns.a: undefined reference to `__dn_expand'
collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
make: *** [smtpd] Fehler 1
```

Problem: missing -lresolv

In file "makedefs": gcc -print-search-dirs | sed -n '/^libraries: =/s/libraries: =//p' didn't work for me, because i have Ubuntu in German language. The gcc -print-search-dirs output is "Bibliotheken:"

See http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?p=287215

Comment: http://irbs.net/internet/postfix/0409/1719.html   CCARGS="-DHAS_CDB -DHAS_PCRE" AUXLIBS="-lnsl -lpcre -lcdb" make makefiles && make -j 3

Answer (score 0):

You should append `-ldb -lnsl -lresolv` to `AUXLIBS`.